# Closing toggle menu not working properly with JQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, menu, toggle

I am working on closing toggle menu for mobiles and having a small problem. So what i want is when the toggle menu is active, user to be able to close it by touching somewhere on the screen on his device. I almost got it working, but when closed the basket in the header disappears and the menu doesn't retrieve to a hamburger icon. I am working on Wordpress website, just to notice.
I guess the problem comes from this: **aria-expanded="true"** , because the default value should be false after the user has closed it.
So my website is:
https://www.ngraveme.com/bg

my JQuery code is:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var $menu = $('.menu');


  $('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
    $menu.toggle();
  });

  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    if (!$menu.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
      &&
      $menu.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
      $menu.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

and the original js code written from the theme i am using in wordpress is:

```js
/**
 * navigation.js
 *
 * Handles toggling the navigation menu for small screens.
 * Also adds a focus class to parent li's for accessibility.
 * Finally adds a class required to reveal the search in the handheld footer bar.
 */
(function() {
  // Wait for DOM to be ready.
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var container = document.getElementById('site-navigation');
    if (!container) {
      return;
    }

    var button = container.querySelector('button');
    if (!button) {
      return;
    }

    var menu = container.querySelector('ul');
    // Hide menu toggle button if menu is empty and return early.
    if (!menu) {
      button.style.display = 'none';
      return;
    }

    button.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
    menu.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
    menu.classList.add('nav-menu');

    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      container.classList.toggle('toggled');
      var expanded = container.classList.contains('toggled') ? 'true' : 'false';
      button.setAttribute('aria-expanded', expanded);
      menu.setAttribute('aria-expanded', expanded);
    });

    // Add class to footer search when clicked.
    document.querySelectorAll('.storefront-handheld-footer-bar .search > a').forEach(function(anchor) {
      anchor.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        anchor.parentElement.classList.toggle('active');
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    });

    // Add focus class to parents of sub-menu anchors.
    document.querySelectorAll('.site-header .menu-item > a, .site-header .page_item > a, .site-header-cart a').forEach(function(anchor) {
      var li = anchor.parentNode;
      anchor.addEventListener('focus', function() {
        li.classList.add('focus');
      });
      anchor.addEventListener('blur', function() {
        li.classList.remove('focus');
      });
    });

    // Add an identifying class to dropdowns when on a touch device
    // This is required to switch the dropdown hiding method from a negative `left` value to `display: none`.
    if (('ontouchstart' in window || navigator.maxTouchPoints) && window.innerWidth > 767) {
      document.querySelectorAll('.site-header ul ul, .site-header-cart .widget_shopping_cart').forEach(function(element) {
        element.classList.add('sub-menu--is-touch-device');
      });
    }
  });

})();
```

Comment: You could try adding `$('.menu-toggle').data('aria-expanded', false)` before `$menu.hide()`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but still not working.. :/

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your jQuery code with this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    var $menuContainer = $('.menu');
    var $menu = $menu.find('ul');
    var $container = $('.site-navigation');
    var $button = $container.find('button')
    if (!$menuContainer.is(e.target) && $menuContainer.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      if ($container.hasClass('toggled')) {
        $button.attr('aria-expanded', false);
        $menu.attr('aria-expanded', false);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

It uses the vanilla-js code from the template for hiding/showing the menu, but with jQuery synthax.

Comment: Replaced it, but this time even the menu isn't hiding after being called..:/